# Changing Android Spinner Layout/Design

Tags: android

I am trying to modify the design of [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) widget. I can change the background, but I can't find a way to change the arrow icon on the right side. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The whole thing is a single 9 patch png image.  I've modified the entire look of spinners before by replacing the images.  See this page: http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

Specifically look at btn_dropdown_normal.9, btn_dropdown_pressed.9, btn_dropdown_selected.9 and btn_dropdown_disabled.9

You just need to provide your own versions of those images.

Comment: How to change this from android.jar.Can you give me any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Guess that site went down, here's another site with the same stuff: http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can place your "spinner bar" layout in a FrameLayout, together with the real spinner but set to invisible:

```
    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        >
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/theSpinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
           />

       <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="32dip"
         android:background="@drawable/my_background"
         android:padding="6dip"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:onClick="spinnerBarReplacementClicked"
       >
       <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/replacementSelectImg"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"   
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"     
          android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
          />    

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/replacementSelectText"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/replacementSelectImg"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

        </RelativeLayout>     
    </FrameLayout>
```

and pass the clicks from your layout to the real spinner

```
    private Spinner mSpinner;

    mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.theSpinner);

    public void spinnerBarReplacementClicked(View pV){
        mSpinner.performClick();
}
```